# Docker: an error happened: ffmpeg exited with code 127

Tags: node.js, docker, ffmpeg, dockerfile

As I mentioned above, when I run the container, I get an error. When I run it normally, it works, there is no problem.

my container run code: docker run --rm -i -t -p 8080:4444 9fa71c8ca9ba

the error i got;
an error happened: ffmpeg exited with code 127

APP.JS

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/znCRWz2rgx/

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:10

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install
RUN npm install fluent-ffmpeg
RUN npm install os
RUN npm install express
RUN npm install --save @google-cloud/text-to-speech
RUN npm install --save @google-cloud/translate
RUN export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="dogwood-cipher-307314-4074350f02b8.json"


CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

Comment: So time to debug your Node app and figure out why.

Comment: My node application works normally. Doesn't work with docker.

Comment: That's why you need to debug it.

Comment: I shared because I could not find the error.

Comment: We're not going to find it either. You need to try and reproduce it and narrow down the causes.

Comment: ffmpeg is a very old build so I am seeing the problem in docker.

Comment: There's not enough information in the question to debug this.  Where does the `ffmpeg` binary come from?  Why are so many things missing from the `package.json` file?  What Javascript code causes the error?

Comment: The code works normally. Docker's making trouble. I did not understand...